# Finite subgroup generated by an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

$G$ is any group with identity element $e$ and $x\in G$. If $\langle x\rangle$ is of finite order $a$, why should $a=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}^*\ |\ x^{n}=e\}$? In fact why should $\{n\in\mathbb{N}^*\ |\ x^{n}=e\}\ne\emptyset$? I am not able to derive a contradiction from the assumption
$$(\forall n)(n\in\mathbb{N}^*\implies x^n\ne e)$$

Comment: Thank you for posting your question. I'm not sure what you mean by $\Bbb{N}^*$. Is $\Bbb{N}^*$ the set of positive integers? Is $\Bbb{N}$ the set of non-negative integers?

Comment: Hi, $\mathbb{N}^*$ is the set of integers $>0$.

Comment: The only time the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}^* \;|\; x^n=e\} = \emptyset$ is if $\langle x\rangle$ is an infinite cyclic group. Because $\infty$ is not a number and $0$ is excluded by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Well if $\langle x\rangle$ has finite order then certainly the elements $x,x^2,\dots,x^k,\dots$ are not distinct, say $x^i=x^j$ for some $0<i<j$. Then $x^{j-i}=e$. Can you take it from there?